# "...rumours online, and AROUND, and ABOUT that it will...."

Tags: prepositions

I was watching a show, where a famous actor is hosted and TV presenter asks him about what will happen in the new episodes to come.

And TV presenter said to actor "There are rumours ONLINE, and AROUND, and ABOUT that another wedding will take place".

I understand her question generally but really wondered why she emphasized seperately the prepositions "AROUND" and "ABOUT" to refer to the rumor. I can understand why she emphasized the word "online" by which she referred to the rumor on the internet. But where did she refer to using the words "AROUND" and and and "ABOUT"?

When I listed all 3 words TV presenter used referring to the rumor, I was able to find two of what might she have referred to, but I think I was not able to find the last one.

To sum up;
- rumors online (rumors on the internet),
- rumors around (rumors in real life, amongst real people)
- rumors about, (?????)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"around and about" is a stock phrase that in this context means rumours heard in unspecific places of everyday life: in the pub, while shopping, at parties, and so forth.  The phrase probably came about more because people liked the way the two words sounded together than because each word was exactly accurate in the context.

About is being used here in the same sense as "man about town": someone you are not surprised to see in the popular places in town, the most fashionable restaurants and bars.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeremy.  In fact I tried to find "around and about" listed in some dictionary, and was disappointed.  But I think the phrase will make more sense to you if you consider one of the more unusual definitions of "about."  Each dictionary does include this definition.  I've chosen one that I think makes it a little clearer than some.

> 22. *adjective* in existence; current; prevalent: *The flu is about.*
>
> [Random House](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/about)